# Gram-Schmidt algorithm and degenerate bilinear forms

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, gram-schmidt

I am studying Gram-Schmidt algorithm on Euclidean spaces(real spaces with a positive definite bilinear form). And I was wondering if this algorithm was valid also in more general spaces. I think that it is valid for a generic vector space with a non-degenerate bilinear form(because if it was degenerate, the denominators of Fourier coefficients could be 0), but I'm not sure:could you help me?
Moreover, are there more general algorithms that work in every possible situation.

Comment: I think the vector space should be finite dimensional and $\langle x,x \rangle \neq 0$ should hold for nonzero $x$ (which is nondegeneracy, right?). Besides that it should work out. I believe you could potentially use nondegenerate sesquilinear forms as well...

Comment: @PrudiiArca No, nondegeneracy is a weaker property: namely, $\ \langle x,  y\rangle =0\ $ for *all* $\ y\ $ implies $\ x=0\ $.  In $\ \mathbb{R}^2\ $,  for instance, $\ (x,y)\mapsto x^\top \pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}y\ $ is a nondegenerate bilinear form, but $\ \pmatrix{1&1} \pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1} \pmatrix{1\\1}=0\ $.  I therefore can't see how the vanilla Gram-Schmidt process can be guaranteed to work  for a *general* nondegenerate bilinear form, though it might, of course, be possible to tweak it in some way so that the tweaked version always works.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera so there should't be isotropic non null vectors right?

Comment: @Eureka That still might not be enough. There's also the problem that a general bilinear form doesn't have to be symmetric, so you can have two vectors $\ x\ $ and $\ y\ $ for which $\ b(x,y)=0\ $ but $\ b(y,x)\ne0\ $, and there would appear to be some ambiguity about what the definition of "orthogonality" should be. I'm fairly sure, however, that the vanilla Gram-Schmidt procedure will work for any *symmetric* bilinear form which has no non null isometric vectors.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera this happens if and only if the bilinear form is positive or negative definite, right?

Comment: @Eureka. For vector spaces over $\ \mathbb{R}\ $, yes, although I wasn't restricting myself to that case. For vector spaces over $\ \mathbb{C}\ $, bilinear forms which are merely *symmetric* are  not so nice. It's the *conjugate* symmetric bilinear forms with no non null isotropic vectors that will be either positive or negative definite.  I don't have much of a feel for what happens for other fields.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera thank you :). Do you know more general orthogonalization algorithms?

Comment: No, I've not come across any others that I can recall. I need to make a correction to  my previous comment, however.  "Conjugate symmetric bilinear forms" for vector spaces over $\ \mathbb{C}\ $ should instead be "conjugate symmetric sesquilinear  forms".